# Regression analysis model vs mathematical model

Tags: mathematical-modeling, regression-analysis

Can anyone explain the difference between the equation generated from a regression analysis as opposed to a mathematical model such as $E = m \cdot {c^2}$ type models?

Comment: If i understand what you're asking, equations from regression analysis come from looking at observed data and trying to match that to some kind of pattern, whereas mathematical models seem to come more from deduction/logic, generally in an idealized setting

Comment: You could write $\$$ e = mc^2 $\$$ in your question. That will result in $ e = mc^2 $. On topic, I agree with what Brent says.

Comment: I think you use regression to find some relations you didn't expect at first, and then look and see what fits the data best. With physical experiments they actually did the same thing, but they didn't use regression explicitly for it. They just looked for a model that seemed to fit the data well. Also most mathematical models are invented before regression analysis even existed. They did it more "manually" and just used common sense (logic & deduction) to find out what were good models.

Comment: Also Newton lived for instance from 1642-1726. The method of least squares was only invented in 1805 by Legendre and in 1809 by Gauss.